# Using PHP Phalcon framework to run on Background

Tags: php, phalcon

My problem might be very basic for you because I'm new to phalcon framework.

I'm building a web-based system were I want to upload an excel file into the server then perform a set of conditions and insert the result into my DB, but I want the excution to be done at the server meaning that user can close the browser but the the system should still process the file and while processing it should show the for the user a process bar.

Comment: Push the job to a queue: https://docs.phalconphp.com/fr/3.3/queue

Answer (score 0):

You can upload file and add it's name to queue system or just store it in database. Phalcon provides Beanstalk support out of the box but if you want keep history (and show progress with ease) of uploads I would recommend database-way. Table structure should contain columns like: file name, processed_rows, rows, status (0 - new, 1 - processed).

To process files in background you can create Phalcon CLI app which should observe queue (or unprocessed files from database) and process files. You should configure CRON task to run it every 1/5/10min depending on how much files you upload or run it in endless loop.

To determine progress you can count all rows in file and update processed rows count while processing. Then you can just calculate progress on client's request.

If you need live progress you can make ajax calls in interval to get current progress from database or implement WebSocket server which will send you progress from another queue's tube (updated by background processing process).